# You got a little butterfly there

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me to understand sentence "You got a little butterfly there when he did a little work on you" in the following dialog in movie "A violent man". Thanks a lot.

> BENJAMIN GREEN: Ty Matthews! Have a seat, take a load off.
>   TY: This is a really, really nice place you have here, Mr. Green.
>   BENJAMIN GREEN: Thank you. You got a little butterfly there, when he did a little work on you.
>   TY: Yeah, it's just part of the game.

Comment: Are there any visual, on screen clues or background that may help? It might be related to "butterflies in the tummy", where Ty was nervous because "he did a little work" (i.e. someone beat him up). Or it could mean that Ty got a nice new tattoo of a little butterfly.

Answer (score 3):

He's talking about a [butterfly bandage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JQKBVYE) (or butterfly closure), which is a type of bandage used on a cut to pull the wound together.

Such bandages are used a lot in boxing and martial arts, so that is the context that is framing the dialogue you linked.

Comment: Thanks for that, Robusto. I thought he had a tattoo!